# Disassemble External HD for internal drives NAS Build Pro/Con

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, nas, freenas

Poked around and I didn't see anythingthat could give me a definitive answer. I am using a Fractal Design Node 304 for a 4-6 Bay DIY Nas build.

I want to fill with as much storage as possible, if course at the best price.

Best value I can currently see is for  4tb external drives and take the  hdd out to use as my internal drive.

[Amazon Seagate 4TB Expansion Drive](http://www.amazon.ca/Seagate-Expansion-Desktop-External-STEB4000100/dp/B00TKFEE8K)

My question is if there would be a disadvantage to doing this instead of buying say WD Green drives at 40-50$$ more? External hdd specs aren't very good usually on websites.

Comment: No warranty, but some companies like backblaze do this anyway.

Comment: I wouldn't touch Seagate, though - based on Backblaze's HD reliability stats & that Apple has just set up a replacement program for them too - https://www.backblaze.com/blog/best-hard-drive/

Comment: Based on https://www.backblaze.com/blog/best-hard-drive/, which I appreciate you sharing, the model of drive I am interested in only has a 3% failure rate, and they have over 1000 of these drives running. I get that the Barracuda 7200rpm drives have over 30% fail rate. But those have been known as a bad drive for quite some time.